# Enable PayPal Website Payments Pro

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am aware that this question has been asked and answered before, however none of the solutions are working for me. I have a Business as well as a Personal account configured in my Sandbox. I added another Business account without much luck in it working.

When I used the API information and test out my application, I get a "You do not have permissions to make this API Call [Code: 10002]".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What API call are you submitting? What is the API username? You may be trying to do something that isn't enabled on the account by default with new business accounts.

Comment: It is using PayPal Direct to process the payment without directing the user to the PayPal website and get the response back...

Comment: What is the API username submitting the call? I can look it up and enable anything on it that needs to be set or help resolve the problem.

Comment: Hi Patrick - Here is the PayPal API username: 'salman.khalid-facilitator_api1.tradepoint360.com'

Answer (score 0):

The "facilitator" account created automatically at Developer.PayPal.com is for creating a set of test REST credentials. The account isn't created to work with Payments Pro or Advanced. The way the account is created prevents us from manually enabling certain features on it as well.

Follow these steps to create a new account with Pro and Recurring Payments enabled on it:

- Log into your Developer.PayPal.com account
- Click on "Applications"
- Click on "Sandbox accounts"
- Click the "Create Account" button in the top right
- Set the country as "United States" and select the account type as "Business"
- Fill out the rest of the fields, do not add an account balance, and click on "Create Account"